# Why do I exit my TabView when navigating to a child view?

Tags: swiftui, tabview

Question. Why do I exit my `TabView` when navigating to a view that is a child of a TabView? I hope I am being clear, but the code below is ready to be copy and pasted and notice how when I navigate to `UnrelatedView` I exit my tabView...

Additional context: The root view `ContentView` in this case is embedded inside of a NavigationView in the App.swift file

```
  import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ViewA()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("A")
                }
            
            ViewB()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("B")
                }
            
            ViewC()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("C")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
 
struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: UnrelatedView()) {
        Text("ViewA")
        }
    }
}


struct ViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ViewB")
    }
}

struct ViewC: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("ViewC")
    }
}

struct UnrelatedView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        Text("Unrelated View")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your navigation in `NavigationView`s.

```
struct ViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: UnrelatedView()) {
                Text("ViewA")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that if I am already in a NavigationView and navigate to a new navigationView I will be doubly stacked. I guess I will have to do away with the initial NavView and just keep them on the destined views

Comment: Yeah, you are free to remove the NavigationView from your destination "UnrelatedView". It will be added to the navigation stack of the view that presented it.